# delete if record exits otherwise exit in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to delete a record if it exist and don't do anything if the record doesn't exist 
I think the delete query alone is not sufficient. because the database throws error if it doesn't find the record. I am using Mysql I am doing this :

```
DELETE from TAG WHERE EXISTS(select * from TAG where column='value')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: MySql do not throw an error, if the record is not found. So delete is sufficient.

Comment: What error do you get if there is no record? O.o

Comment: but it is not working

Comment: paste your error as well

Comment: `DELETE from TAG WHERE column='value'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DELETE tablename WHERE COLUMNNAME =' ';`
This will do what you asked for. If record exists then delete else nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what do you need, but looks like:

```
DELETE from TAG WHERE column='value'
```